# How to fix z-index in my example?

Tags: html, css, z-index, dropdown

I had a navbar that worked as intended until I added some transitions from [this example](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch) to my dropdown menus: they slide from "over" the navbar instead of from under it. I've tried reassigning z-indexes in various ways to no avail. How can I fix that?

<s>Additionally, somehow it also affected the language selection menu (on the right): it's dropdown is supposed to be aligned right, but not it's glitching (if you move cursor to the right edge, it keeps switching before float:right and float:left, somehow).</s> **EDIT:** this glitch is fixed.

It looks [like that](https://codepen.io/iyoossaev/pen/mXgpQg) right now. My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<!-- ########## HEAD ########## -->
<head>
    <!-- ########## META ########## -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Bla</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>

<!-- ########## HEADER ########## -->
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1"><div class="navcont"><span style="visibility: hidden;">&nbsp;</span></div></div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <nav id="navmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Dictionary</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Grammar</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Learn!</span></a></li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Games</span>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Match Words</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Crossword</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Hangman</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Guess!</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Tools</span>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Tool 1</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Tool 2</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>About</span>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>News</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Guide</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Statistics</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sources</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Terms of Use</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="rightside"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/en.png" class="langmenu" style="float: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-top: 3px">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/en.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">English</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/fr.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">French</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/de.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">German</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/ru.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Russian</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/pl.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Polish</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/cz.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Czech</span></a></li>
                                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><img src="img/flags/zh.png" class="langmenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="langmenu">Mandarin</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="rightside"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1"><div class="navcont"><span style="visibility: hidden;">&nbsp;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></div></div>
        </div> 
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#navmenu > ul,
#navmenu > ul li,
#navmenu > ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#navmenu > ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;


  z-index: -20;
}
#navmenu > ul li.hover,
#navmenu > ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  cursor: default;
}
#navmenu > ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  /* drop animation 1 */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
  /* --- */
}
#navmenu > ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#navmenu > ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;


  z-index: -20;
}
#navmenu > ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;

  /* drop animation 2 */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -2;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
  /* --- */
}

#navmenu > ul > li.last ul ul {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 99%;
}
#navmenu > ul > li.last ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#navmenu > ul > li.last {
  text-align: right;
}
/* Theme Styles */
#navmenu > ul {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ed7512;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: #4889f2;
  width: auto;
}
#navmenu > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#navmenu > ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#navmenu > ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
}
#navmenu > ul > li.active {
  background-color: #ed7a1c;
}

#navmenu > ul > li.active:hover {
  background-color: #cc6918;
}
#navmenu > ul > li > a:link,
#navmenu > ul > li > a:active,
#navmenu > ul > li > a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#navmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#navmenu > ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
}
#navmenu > ul li li {
  background-color: #4889f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
#navmenu > ul li.hover,
#navmenu > ul li:hover {
  background-color: #1556bf;
}
#navmenu > ul > li.hover,
#navmenu > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #1556bf;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#navmenu > ul a:link,
#navmenu > ul a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navmenu > ul a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#navmenu > ul a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#navmenu > ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #CCC \9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 150px;
}

#navmenu a, #navmenu li, #navmenu li ul {
    width: auto;
}
#navmenu li {
    position: relative;
}
#navmenu li li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#navmenu li ul {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.langmenu {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#navmenu li.rightside:hover ul{
    left:auto;
    right:0;
}

.rightside {
    float: right !important;
}


/* left and right navbar continuation */
.navcont {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ed7512;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    background: #4889f2;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    font-family: inherit;
}

@charset "UTF-8";

/* allows using FontAwesome in CSS "content" */
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
font-weight: normal;
font-style : normal;
       src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
       src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
             url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}

body {
    background-color: ivory;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.spacer {
    height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.sidemargin {
    visibility: hidden;
}


  [1]: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch
  [2]: https://codepen.io/iyoossaev/pen/mXgpQg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use right:0 instead of left:0 in #navmenu > ul ul

```
#navmenu > ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;

  /* drop animation 1 */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
  /* --- */
}
```

Comment: I actually extracted it so that only the lang menu is aligned to right, but that was the right idea, thanks :) However, I am mostly concerned with the z-index issue, so not accepting is as the answer :(

Comment: are you looking for something like this?
[link](https://codepen.io/amitcheke/pen/MQRGja)

Comment: almost exactly! The only issue is that the orange line is on top of the dropdown… do you think something can be done about it? `#navmenu > ul` has it, so maybe reorder z-axis so that's it `ul > a > ul`?

Comment: Updated #navmenu > ul li:hover > ul  with z-index:1 please have a look at [link](https://codepen.io/amitcheke/pen/MQRGja)

Answer (score 1):

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
> with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
> position:relative, or position:fixed).

```
#navmenu > ul li a {
   position:relative;
   background-color: #4889f2;
}

#navmenu > ul ul {
   z-index: 0;    
}
```

Here is html https://jsfiddle.net/7ghy24qr/

Comment: You seem to have fixed that by adding a background color in #navmenu > ul li a, which produces a weird hover-on-dropdown effect that only highlights the text area, not entire <li> element… Do you think there is a way to avoid this new glitch? ;)